# Bold weight for custom font

Tags: fonts, fontspec, bold

I just found out today about the fontspec package, which I find very useful for fonts that I have installed system-wide.

I'm a big fan of handwriting-like fonts and I happen to love Pecita. So much that I am using it for some articles that I write, for personal use. However, it doesn't come with Bold weight, so I created one for myself, using FontForge. All is going well, OS X recognises this weight now (that I included in the family Pecita), except for LaTeX... So I can use Pecita Bold in Pages, say, but not in LaTeX.

What am I doing wrong? The font appears to be good, it is listed in FontBook (the family Pecita now has Regular and Bold weights), but if I use `\usepackage{fontspec}` `\setmainfont{Pecita}`, it doesn't use bold when I call it with `{\bf Some text that I want in bold}`

Here's my entire document to see if there are any redundancies or conflicts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[margin=1.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Pecita}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\begin{document}
\section{This should be bold}
\textbf{This also should be bold}
This is not bold.
\end{document}
```

If it matters, I am using OS X 10.10.1 with MacTeX and Texpad.

Please excuse me if there is something wrong with my post, but it's my first here.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code a complete example starting with `\documentclass{...}`, and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but it helps to make the question as clear as possible. As well, notice that [`\bf` command is obsolete](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc).

Comment: Thank you very much, Thérèse. You're right in using changes in size or color, but I only wanted the artificial bold for names of theorems, for example. Your suggestion works, nonetheless. I consider my question answered. Thank you again!

Comment: I have changed my comment to an answer just to keep things neat around here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `fontspec` doesn’t find the bold or italic of a font, you sometimes have to help it along.  If the font’s name is Pecita Bold, `\setmainfont{Pecita}[BoldFont={* Bold}]` should work (in older versions of `fontspec`, use `\setmainfont[BoldFont={* Bold}]{Pecita}`).  Section 5.1 of the `fontspec` documentation gives more information about this.